# Using injector.get instead of constructor injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Is there any disadvantage of doing this

```
constructor(public injector: Injector) {}

foo() {
  this.injector.get(SomeService).doStuff();
}
```

instead of this

```
constructor(public service: SomeService) {}

foo() {
  this.service.doStuff();
}
```

besides readability?

I have a quite complicated hierarchy of components extending each other, and I want to avoid having to extend the constructor every time, with like 4 or 5 injected services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between these approaches, but everytime when you do `get` on the injector, you run a function which must go and find your provided service. You can call `get` one time and keep the reference of the service in a property

```
constructor(public injector: Injector) {
    this.someService = this.injector.get(SomeService);
}
```

But I think injecting exact services inside the constructor instead of the `Injector` is more readable.

Comment: Yes, of course I would store the service if I use it multiple times across the class. But is my problem understandable? I have a lot of components that derive from the same parent directive which injects 5 services, but I don't need all these services in the component class of every child. (just looking for best practices here)

Comment: So if you have not common services for each child, means that you don't need inject all services into the parent, so inject `Injector` and for each child get appropriate services. Nothing to think more :)

Comment: Its not related to this question but, can you please let me know why circular dependency error gets resolved when service is injected via injector? Thanks!

Comment: I think, It can't be resolved. Reference is staying as reference.